# Find html tags using RegEx in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need to fing all "table" tags on page with attribute border on the page using Regular Expressions on JavaScript.

How can I do it?

P.S. Please, don't propose me any JQuery (or similar) solutions.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)? You can use CSS selectors to match what you want, without regex.

Comment: yes you can use regex like this. <table.*?border.*?>.*?</table>

Comment: Why can't you use native JS methods? How do you expect to do anything without being able to use native JS? Also, I don't think the querySelector is DOM manipulation.

Comment: If you can't *use native JS methods* (as you put it), then you should [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: It's a task from my mentor. It isn't a trivial task

Comment: @StasKh It's a trick. Tell your mentor that you should use the appropriate tool for the task.

Comment: @RGraham http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261561

Comment: If this is a mentor tak, isn't using SO cheating?

Comment: @Xufox Thanks. I happen to agree with the second answer there. And will continue to post this link where appropriate.

Comment: hope mentor is teaching them how to use regex not dom

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
 document.querySelectorAll("table[border]")
```

Comment: PLease explain your answer in detail

Comment: If your answer is short and link-only you might get negative points. So make it informative so other user also get what you answered.

Answer (score -1):

you can use regex object like this to match table which has border.

```
myTableElement.match(/<table.*?border.*?>.*?<\/table>/gi)
```

or like this

```
var x =  new RegExp(/<table.*?border.*?>.*?<\/table>/gi)

myTableElement.match(x);
```

Comment: Sorry, how can I select all table tags with any attributes except border attribute?

Comment: you can use new RegExp(/<table\s+border=['"].*?['"]\s+>.*<\/table>/)

Comment: Although I'm not the down voter, the reason is probably that you're a enabler. You're giving OP the answer where he is approaching the problem with wrong idea. There is no reason, ever, why you would have to use regex to parse html. Especially with powerful javascript api in browsers, like `document.querySelectorAll`. If this is a homework, stack overflow isn't the right place and whoever gave the homework should read about regexes and how they are *not* meant for parsing html.

Comment: then why it has been downvote i just given some idea

Comment: stackoverflow is for giving some information to the questions